# Parsing local xml android

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I just want to parse a XML next to my java file or in the res/xml folder.
I read lots of post an blogs but it just get more confusing!everyone just call the parse function with an URL!like this

```
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
```

I have this part of code and I don't know how to make it work.

```
Document doc = db.parse("What Should I pass here");
```

I tried R.xml.books it's an Integer and this function wants an Inputstream how should I use this R.xml.books ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [openRawResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource%28int%29).

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.xml.books);
Document doc = db.parse(is);
```

Your question is very difficult to understand. Good English and lots of descriptive info go a long way towards getting answers :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which of two questions you're asking:

1) Q: How do I parse XML on Android?

I'd recommend XmlPullParser, built-in with the Android SDK:

- http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html
- http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidXML/article.html

2) Q: Where do I find a file that's included with my .apk?

The best place is to put it in your "assets" directory:

- http://www.itwizard.ro/android-phone-installing-assets-how-to-60.html